# How do I create a task to read data continuously from a TcpClient using tasks and async methods

Tags: c#, tcpclient, task

I am trying to read data continuously from a TcpClient.
Here is my code snippet.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Read);

task.ContinueWith(ant =>
     Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ant.Exception.Message),
     TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

task.ContinueWith(ant =>
     {
         Log("Log my data");
     });


void Read()   
{
   Task<int> readChunk = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(
              _stream.BeginRead, _stream.EndRead,
              data, bytesRead, data.Length - bytesRead, null,
              TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

   readChunk.ContinueWith(rt => { bytesRead = readChunk.Result; }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted
                                            | TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
}
```

This bit of code works fine, but there maybe more data coming on the stream, so I want it to go back and read again.
Starting another Read task doesn't seem right. I am not familiar with the tasks parallel library. Normally I would have written something like this:

```
while (true)
{
   bytesRead += _stream.Read(data, bytesRead, chunkSize);
   if(bytesRead == BytesExpected)
       break;
}
```

Comment: curious, whats the purpose of this and why not use `BeginRead` for async?

Comment: why do you want to use the TPL? I would just call BeginRead and in the handler spawn a new task(in order not to block the IO thread) to do the job and call BeginRead again.

Comment: @wal `BegingRead` is being used in this too, only via FromAsync. Is that a bad practice?

Comment: @Bond: I don't want to have one thread per client. The clients will always be connected. The idea was to create a thread when there was data, read it, and then release the thread.

Comment: @nunespascal - exactly that's what BeginRead does, it will get a thread from the TP when there is data and will let you process it in your callback. My advice was just to not do the processing there, because it's an IO(vs worker) thread but just spawn a task(which will run on a worker thread). After(or before) spawning the task - just call BeginRead so that you will be notified when more data comes.